# Angular 2 ng build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

So i need to create a build which can work without running a server.

Run `ng build`. Got a `dist` folder.

When i run `index.html` im getting an error like

`GET file:///D:/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

He is searching that `js` file in the root of my D:// drive, not in a project folder

So okay, i removed a `<base href="/">` from my `index.html` and got this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to…, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: No base href set. Please provide a value fo…testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:28631:62) [<root>]", __zone_symbol__message: "No base href set. Please provide a value for the A…HREF token or add a base element to the document."} Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.
at new PathLocationStrategy (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:66150:19) [angular]
at provideLocationStrategy (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:62944:9) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:164:77) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:169:84) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:198:151) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:241:60) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:56323:76) [angular]
at NgModuleFactory.create (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:56291:18) [angular]
at file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:38426:61 [angular]
at Object.onInvoke (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:28762:37) [angular]
at Zone.webpackJsonp.528.Zone.run (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/polyfills.bundle.js:2591:43) [<root> => angular]
at NgZone.run (file:///D:/angular/testing1/dist/vendor.bundle.js:28631:62) [<root>]
```

So `angular2router` doesnt work without `<base>` and `index.html` cannot find my local files with `<base>`

How can i solve it ?

Comment: Just put back <base href="./"> but with .

Answer (score 0):

Use --base-href with an appropriate base

From ng help build:

> --base-href (String) (Default: /)
>   aliases: -bh

Answer (score 0):

Add a "." to your base href, like this:

```
<base href="./">
```

Thanks to Admir's comment, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use below script in index.html.

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' + String(document.location).replace('index.html','') + '">')
</script>
```

let me know it works for you or not.